# Interesting memory issue with event listeners

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let me explain what I mean by "memory". I have a Google Map. I'm making an array of markers for the map and adding listeners to each marker.

```
for( var venue in response.markers ){
    var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(response.markers[venue].GPSX, response.markers[venue].GPSY);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: loc,
        title: response.markers[venue].VenueName,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        alert(venue);
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

By the time the marker is clicked, *venue* has the value of however many things there were in response.markers. How do I get the listener to alert or use the original value venue had at the time of its creation? For example, the first marker should alert 0, the second 1, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a for loop has finished in JavaScript the variables still remain. But they are set to whatever value they ended up with. So venue is the last item in `response.markers` when the click function is eventually called.

I would use the bind method on function to create a new function with the appropriate argument bound at the correct time. Like so:

```
function alertVenue(venue) {
    alert(venue);
}

for( var venue in response.markers ){

    // other stuff goes here

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', alertVenue.bind(this, venue));
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

The benefit of using `bind` is that your stacktrace will look nicer (because alertVenue is a named function) and it's quite clear what is happening when you're reading it as well.

Comment: No problem, if it works for you then please feel free to accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(venue) {
        return function(){alert(venue)};
    }(venue)));
```

to avoid the closure with the outer *venue*.,